# Dependency with android support library not working with project using Androidx

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-jetifier

I'm using a dependacy in my project that uses the Andorid Support Library. My project is using AndroidX and i'm unable to use this dependancy due to a compile time error:

[image]

I have added the following [dependency](https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/LoadingButtonAndroid) to my project:

```
implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.14.0'
```

However, after the Gradle sync I'm unable to use this library, which is a providing a view which subclasses AppCompatButton from the Android support library.

I have previously migrated to AndroidX without a problem and have enabled Jetifier in my Gradle properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

My Gradle version is 4.6
My Android plugin version is 3.2.0
Android Studio version 3.2.1

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding.

It's my understanding that Jetifier should have resolved this Android support dependency in this package for me, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Updating my buildToolsVersion to 28.0.3 after restarting my machine fixed the runtime crashes.

However, the Android Studio IDE still highlights the casting errors, maybe it has cached them incorrectly (they still persist after a clean & rebuild).

Comment: Invalidate cache & restart helped me to escape from the casting errors.